# How to get only year value from persiandate(shams date)

Tags: c#

I have a DateTimePicker which is PersianDate(Shams date).It show the date as Long format . now I want to get only the year or only the month from it... Thanks of all

Comment: `DateTimePicker` has a property named `Value` and it's of type `DateTime`...

Comment: It depends to the custom control which you are using. Standard `DateTimePicker` doesn't support Persian calendar.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you Use it:

```
var myDate = DateTime.Now;
var pc = new PersianCalendar();
var persianYear = pc.GetYear(myDate);
```

dont forget to place the usage.

```
using System.Globalization;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.But I don't want DateTime.now... I want any year that i insert in my datetimepicker box... e.g 1392

Comment: I just placed an example, you need to replace the first line with your own code, the date you get from DateTimePicker.